# Snap an ul right side to a div right side

Tags: html, css

I'm really a dummy when it comes to css, but I have to make this one work in all browsers and i'm kinda stuck.

here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/tenonic/9ZHrD/4/
and here is what i need to achieve
[image]

By using 
position: **absolute, top and left I was able to snap it in chrome**, but in other browsers its slightly off and really skewed on larger(iMac) monitors.

```
position: absolute;
top: 48px;
left: -274px;
```

Comment: Change `left` to `-76px`?

Comment: @kei, Unfortunately the whole approach here is wrong, i already played around with left and top to make it snap. But all the browsers would present id differently and menu will be sticking out of the div.

Comment: Try googling `mega menu`...that might give you some clues.